# how to make this table

Tags: tables

I found an example in Columns spanning multiple rows section in 
[tables examples](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)
I have:

```
\begin
{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l| }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{mytable} \\
\hline  
C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{spring} & \multirow{5}{*}{mvc} & \multirow{3}{*}{pull} & A \\
& B \\
& C \\
& review & A \\
& push & A \\
& boot & same as above & \\
& cloud & same as above & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I wish：
[image: table in my dream]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were only a few `&` missing from the table. Even when you use a `\multirow` you have to put the `&` to go to the next column, otherwise you'll have some text overlapping.

I fixed you table and made a second version of it, with fewer rules, and using the `booktabs` package to give it a cleaner look:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l| }
\hline
C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{spring} & \multirow{5}{*}{mvc} & \multirow{3}{*}{pull} & A \\\cline{4-4}
&&& B \\\cline{4-4}
&&& C \\\cline{3-4}
&& review & A \\\cline{3-4}
&& push & A \\\cline{2-4}
& boot & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{same as above} \\\cline{2-4}
& cloud & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{same as above} \\\cline{2-4}
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 \\ \midrule
\multirow{7}{*}{spring} & \multirow{5}{*}{mvc} & \multirow{3}{*}{pull} & A \\
&&& B \\
&&& C \\\cmidrule{3-4}
&& review & A \\
&& push & A \\\cmidrule{2-4}
& boot & \multicolumn{2}{l}{same as above} \\
& cloud & \multicolumn{2}{l}{same as above} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```